# Is there bootstrap file in Quarkus application ? I can read external config files using spring cloud config server client

Tags: quarkus, spring-cloud-config-server

I can read external config files using spring cloud config server client at runtime, but before the application startup I can't not. I can't use external config files for like database connection or kafka topic. Does anyone know something?

Spring has a file like bootstrap is used before starting application and retrieve all of configurations. But Quarkus client does not do that, It retrieve the properties after application status ready

Comment: there is an extension for spring cloud config https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-cloud-config-client

Comment: Yeah, I know, but there is no support for bootstrap, retrieve the values before application starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `quarkus.config.locations` to load external files from any location: classpath, folder, HTTP, etc (just needs to be a valid URI).

Please check: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#quarkus-config-config_quarkus.config.locations

Comment: I tried this one, that is not what I want. I want to retrieve the properties on bootstrap time, before the application be ready to receive requests.

Comment: I've tried it with a sample project, and I was able to configure my database using an external file with `quarkus.config.locations`. Are you able to provide me with a reproducer so I can have a look?

Comment: It is good to hear, where did you store the properties file?

Comment: You can store it in any place. You can refer to it by name directly if it is in the JVM working directory. It can also be in the classpath. I just placed it in a random directory and then used `-Dquarkus.config.locations=FULL_PATH_TO_FILE`.

Comment: It is not remote? Isn't it? because, I wanna a remote solution, as I said above.

Comment: Yes, you can use `http` as the path to the file location. The response format has to be plain text with key-value pair. Check https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-config/blob/c4af4504c3c04beeb681d618bda3d64bcf3f0f2a/implementation/src/test/java/io/smallrye/config/PropertiesLocationConfigSourceFactoryTest.java#L81-L88